What is the difference between Pranam mantra , dhyana mantra and stotram?
In many Bengali books of deities and mahavidyas , I have encountered two types of mantras of a single deity . The Pranam mantra and the dhyana mantra . What is the difference between them and what should an ordinary householder chant in order to get the deities full blessing ? Also which is stronger to get blessings , a stotra or a mantra? Thank you.

Pranama mantra is usually 1-2 slokas long short eulogy. Dhyanamantra is actually a couple of slokas describing the embodied form of a particular deity. Slokas are just a special form of Sanskrit sentences written in anustup poetical metre. For those having no knowledge in Sanskrit, they mistake all slokas to be mantras.

But what should be the procedure and rules for chanting the dhyana and Pranam mantra?
